# Java: Tricky sorting of prefixed Strings (ArrayLists)

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, split

(No networking knowledge required whatsoever. This is purely String and Lists).

Say I have a function in place, one that accepts a list of String IPv4 dotted address, and sorts them in ascending order. (Not alphabetical, true ip long format sorting). Let's call this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> sortListOfIpv4s(ArrayList<String> unsortedIPv4s);
```

This function already works correctly. Given an input:

```
192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 4.5.6.7, 244.244.244.244, 146.144.111.6
```

It will output the list:

```
4.5.6.7, 8.8.8.8, 146.144.111.6, 192.168.1.1, 244.244.244.244
```

(Let's not get into a debate on whether it should modify the list in place or return a new list. It just returns a new list. **Also, the function cannot be modified because of numerous reasons.**)

However, my input list looks like this:

```
e192.168.1.1, f8.8.8.8, e4.5.6.7, f244.244.244.244, e146.144.111.6
```

When I remove the prefixes (only one of e or f, NOT NECESSARILY alternating) and create a clean array to pass to the sorting function, I lose the prefix information. What I would like is an output of the type:

```
e4.5.6.7, f8.8.8.8, e146.144.111.6, e192.168.1.1, f244.244.244.244
```

Basically, prior to sorting, whatever prefix was present for each element in the unsorted list, the same prefix needs to be added back to the elements in the sorted list.

Caveats:

- An IP Address can repeat in the original list, a maximum of two times
- When repeating twice, each of the two elements will have the same prefix, guaranteed
- Sorting algorithm will not remove duplicates.

A little algorithmic help please? (Remember, we already have a function that can sort clean IPv4 String arraylists).

Comment: Are you saying you want to treat `sortListOfIpv4s` as a black box? You're not allowed to change it?

Comment: Precisely. Team environment, large team, and it's a library function not meant to altered for every unique use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remove the prefixes prior to passing it to the sorting function. Instead, in the `sortListOfIpv4s` method, always compare Strings using `s.substring(1)`, which will give you the entire string without the prefix, and add `s` to the resulting sorted array.

If `sortListOfIpv4s` is a *black box* and you are required to pass the prefix-free Strings, then you could cache the prefixes beforehand in a `Map` from `prefix-free IP -> prefix`:

```
Map<String, String> prefixMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String ip : unsortedIPv4s) {
  prefixMap.put(ip.substring(1), ip.substring(0, 1));
}
```

Then sort and recover the prefixes from the `Map`:

```
List<String> sortedIPV4s = sortListOfIpv4s(unsortedIPv4s);
for (String ip : sortedIPV4s) {
  String prefix = prefixMap.get(ip);
  String originalIp = prefix + ip;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. It's a library function and it's being used heavily by other developers. It would be met with a lot of criticism if I demanded that it be modified for this particular scenario. So I have to make a wrapper function around it.

Comment: No. I have already mentioned under caveats that if an IP repeats twice, in the original unsorted list, then both are guaranteed to have the same prefix.

Comment: @refactor.me: Ok, then you can cache the prefixes before sorting the list, and recover them later from the cached map. See my updated answer.

Comment: Flawless victory. It's 4 a.m. and my brain isn't really working. Thanks for the quick help. Much appreciated. Answer accepted.

Comment: Implementing a proper search using an easy and fast to write comparator in java would be much cleaner and much more efficient than to move the prefix out of the way, buffering it and concatenating it again. Mind that string operations are quite expensive, as these buggers are immutable types.

Answer (score 0):

Your method could move any prefix to the end of the String, sort the list, and then go through the Strings again and move the prefixes from the end back to the start.

Comment: That would do the job, but would be pretty ugly. It's pretty easy to implement a custom sort that can deal with the prefix in java, rather than move the prefix out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Comparator:

```
public class IpComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String ipA, String ipB) {
        return doComparison( ipA.substring(1), ipB.substring(1) );
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
return Collections.sort(unsortedIPv4s, new IpComparator());
```